# float right in react native with flexbox

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to float the button to the right side of the maps. Somehow it doesn't work. Can anybody help?

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'purple',
    width,
    height,
  },
  button: {
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'red',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using "alignSelf" layout props for your button as follows:

```
button: {
   alignSelf: 'flex-end',
   borderRadius: 4,
   borderWidth: 2,
   borderColor: 'red'
}
```

Comment: Thanks this one actually worked. I also had to change the component to 'buttonStyle' instead if 'style':

Comment: @dropcunts, If this answer worked for you, can you please accept it as an answer and upvote if possible?

Comment: it seems like I have not enough reputation jet to upvote sorry :/ sorry how can I accept it as anwer i'm new here.

Comment: @dropcunts, not an issue. BTW one can see the check-mark at the left side of the answer and once clicked, the answer get accepted. As you said earlier that you don't have enough reputation, hence you are not able to see that option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an absolute position like this :

```
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: YOUR_WIDTH,
    height: YOUR_HEIGHT,
    right: 20,
  }
```